# Does subtracting Two polynomial having atleast 1 common zero gives the common factor of both the polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

for example here is a question

if $p(x)=x^2+bx+c$ and it is the common factor of both $g(x)=x^4+6x^2+25$ and $f(x)=3x^4+4x^2+28x+5$
find the value of p(1) if b,c belong to integer

in this question by multiplying the $g(x)$ by 3 and subtracting $f(x)$ we get $-14x^2+28x-70$

$=-14(x^2-2x+5)$

now can we conclude that the common factors p(x) is equal as $x^2-2x+5?$ if yes then why?

Comment: "*can we conclude...*" — No, for that you must show that 1) it *is* a factor of $f$ and $g$ in the first place, and 2) the quotients by this common factor are coprime i.e. there is no other common factor.

Comment: @dxiv ,can't it be generalized?i mean if two polynomials have common factor and if they are subtracted then the common factor of both polynomials is also an common factor of their subtraction?

Comment: Yes, but that's a one-way implication, only. It is *not* true that a factor of the difference must be a common factor of the two polynomials, which is what the question seems to be asking. Try for example with $f(x)=x+1$, $g(x)=x^2+1$, then $g(x)-f(x)=x^2-x=x(x-1)$ but neither $x$ nor $x-1$ is a common factor of the two polynomials.

Comment: @dxiv,but for generalization,there is asked if they two polynomials have common zero,but f(x)=x+1 , g(x)=x^2+1 don't have a common zero,can it be generalized using this?

Comment: You can multiply $f$ and $g$ in my example by another polynomial, then they'll have common zero(s), but their difference will still not be the common factor. You *can* get the $\gcd$ by euclidean division *if* you carry it out to the end, but just doing an arbitrary subtraction is not enough to prove it.

Comment: @dxiv,i don't know how to thank you,thanks a lot,I was confused about it since a long time

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi you may answer your question so that it is better for you and the site

Comment: $p \mid f, g \implies p \mid (f-3g) = -14(x^2-2x+5)$. Now **in addition as we are given** that $p$ is a monic quadratic, you can indeed conclude something in this particular case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can Make the following conclusions to answer the question based on the discussion,

Consider polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $p$ and $g(x)$ of degree $g$,let common factor of these two polynomials be $f(x)$,the maximum degree of $f(x)$ can be $min(p,g)$

now the one way implication is that if $f|p$ and $f|g$ then $f|k_1p-k_2g$ (where $k_1,k_2$ are any real numbers),that is if $f(x)$ is common factor of $p(x)$ and $g(x)$ ,then it is also a common factor of $k_1p(x)-k_2g(x)$,this also includes the case when $k_1=1,k_2=1$,$f(x)$ divides $p(x)-g(x)$

this does not necessarily mean the factor of $k_1p(x)-k_2g(x)$ must always be a factor of p(x) as well as g(x),an easy example would be $$8|56$$$$8|384$$
hence $$8|384-56$$ $i.e$ $$8|328$$

but the other way implication that is $$41|328$$$$41|384-56$$ so $41|384$ and $41|56$ is obviously not true and is not always true for all cases

one can also understand that if 8 is $gcd(56,384)$,8 must be $gcd(56,328)$ and $gcd(384,328)$,in general if $gcd(p,q)=r$

$$gcd(p-q,p)=gcd(p-q,q)=r$$

now knowing all that was first part of question,now for solving the question given that $p(x)$ is a factor

$f(x)-3g(x)=-14(x^2-2x+5)$

now as p(x) is given as monic quadratic and the difference $f(x)-3g(x)=-14(x^2-2x+5)$

$p(x)$ must be a factor of that difference,as difference is itself a quadratic and $p(x)$ is monic ,it can now be concluded that $p(x)$ must be $(x^2-2x+5)$,hence $p(1)=4$

this conclusion might not always hold true,suppose in this case the difference came out to be cubic or quartic,then one would need more specific conditions on $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to reach exact value of $p(x)$